# Сконвертировать минуты в часы+минуты при помощи momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Как сконвертировать минуты в часы? Например, у меня есть число 61, что равняется одному часу и одной минуте. Как мне число 61 превратить в '1ч. 1м'? Моя конструкция не работает:

```
let time = moment(moment.duration(num, 'minutes')).format('Hч. Mм.');
```

Answer (score 5):

При помощи momentjs это сделать невозможно, поскольку в moment временные рамки чётко зафиксированы. Если часов более 24, то счётчик пойдет заново. Есть замечательная функция, которая превращает минуты в формат `HHч. mmм.`:

```
function getTimeFromMins(mins) {
    let hours = Math.trunc(mins/60);
    let minutes = mins % 60;
    return hours + ':' + minutes;
};
```

```js
function getTimeFromMins(mins) {
    let hours = Math.trunc(mins/60);
 let minutes = mins % 60;
 return hours + 'ч. ' + minutes + 'м.';
};

console.log(getTimeFromMins(60));
console.log(getTimeFromMins(122));
console.log(getTimeFromMins(228));
console.log(getTimeFromMins(1337));
```